# Why do I get a CORS issue on only some of my API endpoints?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, cors

I am having a problem with my API endpoints. I am using flask for my backend, and for frontend just js, html/css, react.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

@app.route('/users/login', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def user_logon():
    if request.is_json:
```

I looked around and i thought this was working. It worked for a similar endpoint, but the one above it doesnt work for. I tried adding headers in the front end, but that didn't work. I am not sure why one works and the other doesnt when they are the exact same.

I keep getting the classic cors error

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/users/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I'm very confused lol

Comment: So a request to the same endpoint can do both or is it different endpoints? `adding headers in the front end` will never work since CORS is a method for servers to protect resources from being borrowed unscrupulously

Comment: No it's different endpoints. Maybe I'll edit my original comment for clarity. But it's two different endpoints, each created the same way. When I call one of them, it works just fine. When I call the other one, I get a CORS error. But they both should be the exact same, as I do everything the same in both front end and back end

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker Provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example